# Find position of first non-zero decimal

Tags: regex, string, stata

Suppose I have the following local macro:

```
loc a = 12.000923
```

I would like to get the decimal position of the first non-zero decimal (`4` in this example).

There are many ways to achieve this. One is to treat `a` as a string and to find the position of `.`:

```
loc a = 12.000923
loc b = strpos(string(`a'), ".")
di "`b'"
```

From here one could further loop through the decimals and count since I get the first non-zero element. Of course this doesn't seem to be a very elegant approach.

Can you suggest a better way to deal with this? Regular expressions perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straighforward answer uses regular expressions and commands to work with strings.
One can select all decimals, find the first non 0 decimal, and finally find its position:

```
loc v  = "123.000923"

loc v2 = regexr("`v'", "^[0-9]*[/.]", "")      // 000923
loc v3 = regexr("`v'", "^[0-9]*[/.][0]*", "")  // 923
loc first = substr("`v3'", 1, 1)               // 9
loc first_pos = strpos("`v2'", "`first'")      // 4: position of 9 in 000923

di "`v2'"
di "`v3'"
di "`first'" 
di "`first_pos'"
```

Which in one step is equivalent to:

```
loc first_pos2 = strpos(regexr("`v'", "^[0-9]*[/.]", ""), substr(regexr("`v'", "^[0-9]*[/.][0]*", ""), 1, 1))
di "`first_pos2'"
```

An alternative suggested in another answer is to compare the lenght of the decimals block cleaned from the 0s with that not cleaned.
In one step this is:

```
 loc first_pos3 = strlen(regexr("`v'", "^[0-9]*[/.]", "")) - strlen(regexr("`v'", "^[0-9]*[/.][0]*", "")) + 1
 di "`first_pos3'"
```

Comment: Did you try to translate my solution in Stata ? I'm curious if it's possible ;)

Comment: It's similar in a way, the main difference is that I am not comparing the two lenghts, instead I directly  find the position of the first decimal "cleaned" from the zeros by  using `strpos`, but either approach is fine, thanks!

Comment: Ok thanx ;) To optimize your code, first regex can be replaced with `^\d+\.` and the second one with `^0+`

Answer (score 3):

Well, I don't know Stata, but according to the [documentation](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/regular-expressions/), `\.(0+)?` is suported and it shouldn't be hard to convert this 2 lines JavaScript function in Stata.

It returns the position of the first nonzero decimal or -1 if there is no decimal.

```
function getNonZeroDecimalPosition(v) {
  var v2 = v.replace(/\.(0+)?/, "")
  return v2.length !== v.length ? v.length - v2.length : -1
}
```

**Explanation**

> We remove from input string a dot followed by optional consecutive zeros.
>   The difference between the lengths of original input string and this new string gives the position of the first nonzero decimal

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EjKfOn/1)

**Sample Snippet**

```js
function getNonZeroDecimalPosition(v) {
  var v2 = v.replace(/\.(0+)?/, "")
  return v2.length !== v.length ? v.length - v2.length : -1
}

var samples = [
  "loc a = 12.00012",
  "loc b = 12",
  "loc c = 12.012",
  "loc d = 1.000012",
  "loc e = -10.00012",
  "loc f = -10.05012",
  "loc g = 0.0012"
]

samples.forEach(function(sample) {
  console.log(getNonZeroDecimalPosition(sample))
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in `mata` in one line ***and*** without using regular expressions:

```
foreach x in 124.000923 65.020923 1.000022030 0.0090843 .00000425 {
    mata: selectindex(tokens(tokens(st_local("x"), ".")[selectindex(tokens(st_local("x"), ".") :== ".") + 1], "0") :!= "0")[1]
}

4
2
5
3
6
```

Below, you can see the steps in detail:

```
. local x = 124.000823

. mata:

: /* Step 1: break Stata's local macro x in tokens using . as a parsing char */
: a = tokens(st_local("x"), ".")

: a
            1        2        3
    +----------------------------+
  1 |     124        .   000823  |
    +----------------------------+

: /* Step 2: tokenize the string in a[1,3] using 0 as a parsing char */
: b = tokens(a[3], "0")

: b
         1     2     3     4
    +-------------------------+
  1 |    0     0     0   823  |
    +-------------------------+

: /* Step 3: find which values are different from zero */
: c = b :!= "0"

: c
       1   2   3   4
    +-----------------+
  1 |  0   0   0   1  |
    +-----------------+

: /* Step 4: find the first index position where this is true */
: d = selectindex(c :!= 0)[1]

: d
  4

: end
```

You can also find the position of the string of interest in Step `2` using the
same logic.

This is the index value after the one for `.`:

```
. mata: 

: k = selectindex(a :== ".") + 1

: k
  3

: end
```

In which case, Step `2` becomes:

```
. mata: 

: 
: b = tokens(a[k], "0")

: b
         1     2     3     4
    +-------------------------+
  1 |    0     0     0   823  |
    +-------------------------+

: end
```

For unexpected cases without decimal:

```
foreach x in 124.000923 65.020923 1.000022030 12 0.0090843 .00000425 {
    if strmatch("`x'", "*.*") mata: selectindex(tokens(tokens(st_local("x"), ".")[selectindex(tokens(st_local("x"), ".") :== ".") + 1], "0") :!= "0")[1]
    else display "  0"
}

4
2
5
0
3
6
```

Answer (score 2):

Not using regex but log10 instead (which treats a number like a number), this function will:

- For numbers >= 1 or numbers <= -1, return with a positive number the number of digits to the left of the decimal.
- Or (and more specifically to what you were asking), for numbers between 1 and -1, return with a negative number the number of digits to the right of the decimal where the first non-zero number occurs.

```
digitsFromDecimal = (n) => {
    dFD = Math.log10(Math.abs(n)) | 0;
    if (n >= 1 || n <= -1) { dFD++; }
    return dFD;
}

var x = [118.8161330, 11.10501660, 9.254180571, -1.245501523, 1, 0, 0.864931613, 0.097007836, -0.010880074, 0.009066729];
x.forEach(element => {
    console.log(`${element}, Digits from Decimal: ${digitsFromDecimal(element)}`);
});

// Output
// 118.816133, Digits from Decimal: 3
// 11.1050166, Digits from Decimal: 2
// 9.254180571, Digits from  Decimal: 1
// -1.245501523, Digits from Decimal: 1
// 1, Digits from Decimal: 1
// 0, Digits from Decimal: 0
// 0.864931613, Digits from Decimal: 0
// 0.097007836, Digits from Decimal: -1
// -0.010880074, Digits from Decimal: -1
// 0.009066729, Digits from Decimal: -2
```

Answer (score 0):

Mata solution of Pearly is very likable, but notice should be paid for "unexpected" cases of *"no decimal at all"*.

Besides, the regular expression is not a too bad choice when it could be made in a memorable 1-line.

```
loc v  = "123.000923"
capture local x = regexm("`v'","(\.0*)")*length(regexs(0))
```

Below code tests with more values of v.

```
foreach v in 124.000923 605.20923 1.10022030 0.0090843 .00000425 12 .000125 {
capture local x = regexm("`v'","(\.0*)")*length(regexs(0))
di "`v': The wanted number = `x'"
}
```